# WordPress Customizer Panels in separate files

Tags: theme-customizer

Is it ok to have each panel in separate file and then call it as below

```
function themeslug_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
   require_once( get_template_directory() .'/inc/customizer/general-settings.php' );  
add_action( 'customize_register', 'themeslug_customize_register' );
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Surely. You are free to structure your code at your convenience as long as it works and its easily readable. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. In fact, I would consider requiring files in this way to be a best practice.